# Algorithm for undirected projective dependency parsing

Tags: algorithms, graphs, parsers

I am looking for an algorithm that will get an optimal projective undirected dependency parse.

That is, given the sentence 'Mary does love John', and an edge-weight function $f$ (that is, a function from pairs of words in the sentence to real numbers), like

> $f$(Mary,does)  = 1
>
> $f$(Mary,love)  = 5
>
> $f$(Mary,John)  = 2
>
> $f$(does,love)  = 2
>
> $f$(does,John)  = 3
>
> $f$(love,John)  = 5

I want an algorithm that will give the edges of the maximum projective spanning tree as: 
{(Mary,love), (does,love), (love,John)} with a total weight of 12.  That is, it should give this:

[image]

Crucially, the algorithm shouldn't give {(Mary,love), (does,John), (love,John)}, even though it has a higher weight of 13, because in that case the dependencies are not projective (the arcs (Mary,love), (does,John) cross each other). That is, it should **not** give this:

[image]

---

Equivalently, I am asking: what algorithms exist for finding a Minimum/Maximum Spanning Tree on an ordered graph, such that the resulting structure is projective?  A bit more formally: given a totally ordered set of nodes $(S,<)$, and a edge weight function $W: S × S → ℝ$,  is there a good algorithm for finding the optimal-weight spanning tree over this set of nodes, such that the resulting structure has the property that every sub-tree is contiguous in the ordering (for any subtree $T$, for all $t,s$ in $T$ there is no $r$ not in $T$ such that $t<r<s$)?

- Without the projectivity requirement, any classic MST algorithm will do (such as [Prim's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), or [Kruskal's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)).
- With the projectivity requirement, but for *directed* graphs/dependencies [Eisner's](https://cs.jhu.edu/~jason/papers/eisner.coling96.pdf) [algorithm](https://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs470/2014--15-fall/14f-lecnotes/lec35.html) (a faster version of Arc-factored Projective Parsing) is standard for getting the optimal directed projective dependency parse.

I am looking for a (probably [CYK](https://www.xarg.org/tools/cyk-algorithm/)-like) algorithm like Eisner's, but which will work on undirected dependency parsing. That is, an algorithm for finding the maximum projective spanning tree for undirected ordered graphs.  Or, perhaps, a proof that Eisner's algorithm will with some modification to work on undirected graphs will be guaranteed to give the optimal projective spanning tree.